# Elasticsearch compare fields without using scripts

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone guide me how to compare two fields - something like inner join, under one index without using script filters in **Elasticsearch**. I can not use script because in that case I would need to change the settings that would be CPU intensive.

eg:

```
 ENT_VERTEX_OLD.ip_address <=> ENT_VERTEX_NEW.ip_address
```

Comment: Why don't you do that comparison at indexing time and store true/false in another field?

Comment: @Val well if he always does that check on only one pair that's ok, if he has more pairs like that it would require storing a lot of redundant data I guess

Comment: @Nisha unfortunately there's no way to do that, you need either a script query or get all the records and filter them out in your application

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk redundant fields are perfectly ok as long as they allow you to improve the performance of your queries. ES loves denormalization :-)

Comment: @Val Kindly explain your solution bit elaborately. However we are now thinking to handle this in the spark jobs itself.

Comment: When you create your document to be indexed, you perform that comparison in your client code and store the result in another boolean field `ip_matches: true/false` of the document. Then at query time you can simply run a `term` query on that field.